# on click submit call php page with parameter from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My home.php page having one selection box with three values names are: PS, RFM and BOTH. If I select "PS" it will show 5 textboxes (names are: PS1, BM, VTC, Branch and REPOSITORY) along with "SUBMIT" and "RESET" button. If I select "RFM" it will show 5 textboxes (names are: Med, Veg, FRM3, Branch type and URL ) along with "SUBMIT" and "RESET" button. If I select "BOTH" it will show all 10 above mentioned text boxes, SUBMIT and RESET. Now i want to know the code for Eg: I selected "PS" it will show 5 textboxes (names are: PS1, BM, VTC, Branch and REPOSITORY), after filling all the field I will click on "SUBMIT" button. So onclick on "SUBMIT" button it should call test.php page with above mentioned 5 parameters (If I select BOTH parameters are 10). How can i make script work like this?

home.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#integ").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "PS") {
                $("#psval").show();
                $("#bmval").show();
                $("#vtcval").show();
                $("#brnchval").show();
                $("#repval").show();
                $("#medval").hide();
                $("#vegval").hide();
                $("#frmval").hide();
                $("#branchval").hide();
                $("#urlval").hide();
                $("#sub").show();

            } else if ($(this).val() == "RFMSW") {
                $("#psval").hide();
                $("#bmval").hide();
                $("#vtcval").hide();
                $("#brnchval").hide();
                $("#repval").hide();
                $("#medval").show();
                $("#vegval").show();
                $("#frmval").show();
                $("#branchval").show();
                $("#urlval").show();
                $("#sub").show();

            } else if ($(this).val() == "BOTH") {
                $("#psval").show();
                $("#bmval").show();
                $("#vtcval").show();
                $("#brnchval").show();
                $("#repval").show();
                $("#medval").show();
                $("#vegval").show();
                $("#frmval").show();
                $("#branchval").show();
                $("#urlval").show();
                $("#sub").show();

            } else {
                 window.location = "ps_rfm_int.php";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<span>Type</span>
<select id="integ">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="PS">PS</option>
    <option value="RFMSW">RFM</option>
    <option value="BOTH">BOTH</option>
</select>
<!--<hr />-->
<div id="psval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">PS1</td><td><input type="text" id="psver" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="bmval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">BM</td><td><input type="text" id="bmver" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="vtcval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">VTC</td><td><input type="text" id="vtcver" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="brnchval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">Branch</td><td><input type="text" id="brnchver" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="repval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">REPOSITORY</td><td><input type="text" id="repver" /></td></tr></table>
</div>


<div id="medval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">Med:</td><td><input type="text" id="med" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="vegval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">Veg:</td><td><input type="text" id="veg" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="frmval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">FRM3:</td><td><input type="text" id="frm" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="branchval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">Branch type:</td><td><input type="text" id="branch" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="urlval" style="display: none">
</br><table><tr><td width="150px">URL:</td><td><input type="text" id="url" /></td></tr></table>
</div>

<div id="sub" style="display: none">
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.
Mahadev

Comment: And your current script isn't working? - And where is the form?

Comment: @Epodax: Thanks for the response. I don't know how to add form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any ajax call in your code. if you want to call your php page with ajax and send your data to it use like this:(in simple way)

jQuery:

```
var val=$("#integ").val(); // select every item you want to send
$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "php file url",
            data : {
                myData: val, // you can add more data with , 
                myData2:val2 // ....
        }.done(function(msg) {
           alert("send successfully");
        });
```

and in your php file you can use the value like this:

```
$data=$_POST["myData"];
echo $data;
```

****EDIT:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var val=$("#integ").val(); // select every item you want to send
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "php file url",
            data : {
               myData: val, // you can add more data with , 
               myData2:val2 // ....
           }.done(function(msg) {
                 alert("send successfully");
           });
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't get where exactly i need to add jquery for calling php script?

Comment: Your wellcome, see EDIT part in Answer.. :)

Comment: @ Mohsen Shakibafar : Thanks for the help. It's working now.